# Issues with logical variables and loops

Tags: r, loops, logical-operators

on the code below I am running into an error:

Runtime error
Error in while (x0tol) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Execution halted

If I comment out the loop, x0tol returns TRUE and class logical.  What am I missing?  Thank you in advance.

```
a = c(1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,6,8,10)
b = c(-890,1411,-1560,-2220,-2091,-2878,-3537,-3268,-3920,-4163,-5471,-5157)
data = data.frame(a,b)
tol = .0001
m = dim(data)[1]
x0 = 0
x1 = 0
x0temp = 1
x1temp = 1
alpha  = 1
x0tol = TRUE
while(x0tol){
    x0sum = 0
    x1sum = 0
    for (i in 1:m){ 
        x0sum = x0 + x1*data[m,1] - data[m,2]
        x1sum = (x0 + x1*data[m,1] - data[m,2])*data[m,1]
    }
    x0temp = x0 - alpha*1/m*x0sum
    x1temp = x1 - alpha*1/m*x1sum
    x0tol = (abs(x0 - x0temp) > tol) 
    x1tol = x1 - x1temp
    x0 = x0temp
    x1 = x1temp
    class(x0tol)
    x0tol
}
```

Comment: `x0tol` becomes NA in the loop (because `x0` becomes NaN and `abs(NaN)>0` s NA). `while(NA)` generates the error you are getting. You didn't describe the intent so it's unclear what behavior you expected.

Comment: In addition, x0 goes to -Inf, which is probably not desired.

Comment: I as attempting to program a simple linear regression model for two unknown parameters.  The desired results is that x0 and x1 converge to the estimate values based upon the data provided.  This should be less than some tolerance value.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it is assuming there is an NA value in the condition of your while loop. Simply change the statement and create an If statement with a break should allow the loop to function. Cheers

```
while(TRUE){
  x0sum = 0
  x1sum = 0
  for (i in 1:m){ 
    x0sum = x0 + x1*data[m,1] - data[m,2]
    x1sum = (x0 + x1*data[m,1] - data[m,2])*data[m,1]
  }
  x0temp = x0 - alpha*1/m*x0sum
  x1temp = x1 - alpha*1/m*x1sum
  if (abs(x0 - x0temp) > tol){break}
  x1tol = x1 - x1temp
  x0 = x0temp
  x1 = x1temp
  class(x0tol)
  x0tol
}
```